# Validating multiple sections of the page, but only having one submit button

Tags: validation

I am writing a page that has one form tag and one submit button, but has multiple spots for input....

```
<form>
...
</table class="t1">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name1" /></td>
    <td><input name="stDate" /></td>
    <td><input name="endDate" /></td>
    <td><input name="description1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="t2">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name2" /></td>
    <td><input name="date2" /></td>
    <td><input name="description2" /></td>
    <td><input name="email2" /></td>
    <td><input name="id2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="t3">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name3" /></td>
    <td><input name="date3" /></td>
    <td><input name="description3" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
....
  <div align="center" class="submit">
    <input class="submit" width="10%" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

None of these fields are required, the user can fill out every field or doesn't have to fill out any of the fields.  Where I run into the problem is, if the user fills out the any of the fields on table "t1" then I need to require that the other fields be filled out as well for table "t1".....and the same for table "t2" and "t3".  --Also, note, the input fields are unique, bc I am writing to a DB after submit. Thanks for the help, and please request more info it if is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate_form();">
...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_form(){
        var name_list = document.getElementsByName('name');
        var date_list = document.getElementsByName('date');
        var desc_list = document.getElementsByName('description');
        var is_valid = true;
        for( var i=0; i<name_list.length; i++ ){
            var n = name_list[i].value.length > 0;
            var d = date_list[i].value.length > 0;
            var ds = desc_list[i].value.length > 0;
            if( !( (n && d && ds) || (!n && !d && !ds) ) ) {
                is_valid = false;
            }
        }

        return is_valid;
    }
</script>
```

Something like that anyway

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use getElementsByName. Then you will get arrays of name, date and description. Then you can iterate through them and make sure that if name[0] is not blank then date[0] and description[0] are not blank etc.

**Update to support the updated question:**

In that case a better option would be to use jquery which provides easier syntax for doing the same. You can have a dummy css class to use for your tables that form the FORM sections. e.g.

```
<table class="t1 formsection">
```

"formsection" is the dummy css class.

Then using jquery you can get $(".formsection") which will give all the form sections. JQuery allows you to get the children of a specific element type of a given element. Using that you can get the input elements for a each of the form section.

Once you have that you can loop through those input elements to see if all are blank or all arte filled.

Comment: post is edited now, that was just a small example, the tables all have a different number of input fields.  Would this still work in that case?  I am even unsure how to run any kind of validation script on an array like that.